# Brain.js guessing whether adult or child based on height/weight

Tags: javascript, brain.js

I am trying to set up a simplistic brain.js example to get a feel for how it works. I used [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/9Hz3P1VgLz4?t=5m10s) (5:10 mark for adult/child example). My code looks like this:

```js
var brain = require("brain.js");

const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

network.train([
  {input:{height:1, weight:20},output:{adult:0}},
  {input:{height:2, weight:40},output:{adult:0}},
  {input:{height:3, weight:60},output:{adult:0}},
  {input:{height:4, weight:80},output:{adult:0}},
  {input:{height:5, weight:100},output:{adult:0}},
  {input:{height:5, weight:200},output:{adult:1}},
  {input:{height:6, weight:220},output:{adult:1}},
  {input:{height:7, weight:240},output:{adult:1}},
  {input:{height:8, weight:260},output:{adult:1}},

]);


const testPerson = network.run({height:1,weight:20})
console.log(testPerson)
```

So clearly, if you're 4 feet or less you're a child and if you're 6 feet or more you're an adult. If you're 5 feet, then it depends on your weight.

But if I put a clear child in there (the `testPerson`), I get returned:

```
{ adult: 0.4641557037830353 }
```

Seems like based on the data, it should be more confident that a 1 foot 20 pound person is not an adult.

What am I missing here about how this software works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to normalize your inputs: https://jsfiddle.net/robertleeplummerjr/jn056e7L/5/

```
const network = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

network.train([
  {input:{height:1, weight:20},output:{child:1}},
  {input:{height:2, weight:40},output:{child:1}},
  {input:{height:3, weight:60},output:{child:1}},
  {input:{height:4, weight:80},output:{child:1}},
  {input:{height:5, weight:100},output:{child:1}},
  {input:{height:5, weight:200},output:{adult:1}},
  {input:{height:6, weight:220},output:{adult:1}},
  {input:{height:7, weight:240},output:{adult:1}},
  {input:{height:8, weight:260},output:{adult:1}},
].map(normalize))


const testChild = network.run(normalizeInput({height:2,weight:20}))
console.log('a child', testChild)
const testAdult = network.run(normalizeInput({height:5,weight:200}))
console.log('an adult', testAdult)

function normalize(item) {
  return {
    input: normalizeInput(item.input),
    output: item.output
  }
}

function normalizeInput(input) {
    return {
    height: input.height / 10,
    weight: input.weight / 300
  };
}
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Being new to this, I don't see why this should be required...not everything works perfectly as a value between 0 and 1. Wouldn't a 400 lb guy throw the whole scale off?

Comment: There are some tricks that we can use that help us subvert this, but really we are talking about math.  Brain.js does a good job both keeping close to the math and keeping close to the raw heavy lifting of neural networks.

We could probably add a normalize function that takes care of a lot of this automatically.

Comment: Coming back to this question, and ignoring the methods we could build.  The why of it is this: height is on a scale of what looks like 1-10, weight is on a scale of 1-300, and child & adult are on a scale of 0-1.  The reason you need to normalize the values so they are on the same scale, is very similar to what happens when someone whispers into your ear, and then yells, and it hurts because you've adjusted to a lower volume.  Inverted it works similarly: go to a concert, and then just after try hearing someone whisper.  Normalizing values puts everything within a range that can be understood.